# How to show user's udt definition in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, user-defined-types

I know the udt definition relies on pg_catalog.pg_type, but is there another table where I can get its columns/elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns of user defined types can be read from the [`pg_attribute`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-attribute.html) table:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pg_attribute
WHERE  attrelid::regclass = 'my_type_schema.my-type_name'::regclass
```

Where the type name can optionally be schema-qualified. I wrote about `pg_attribute` and `regclass` in many related answers. Search for more ...

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I found a bit tricky to search about udt elements without knowing about "pg_attribute".